# Write a string to a serial port in Java

Tags: java, serial-communication

I want to write a string to a serial port, but serial port write method allows only byte array. How can I send whole string to a port?

Here is my code:

```
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(300,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();

String mValue = "ABCDEFG";
System.out.println("beginning to Write . \r\n");
mOutputToPort.write(mValue.getBytes());
System.out.println("AT Command Written to Port. \r\n");
mOutputToPort.flush();
```

I don't want to send it one by one char. I want whole String at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works (it does write the whole string at once), but it is not nice. If this is what you intend to do, the "clean" way to do it is:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mOutputToPort));
bw.write(mValue);
// probably "write" some more here to the buffer
bw.flush(); // now ensure accumulated data is actually written
```

If you are only writing one string and not more you might as well use an OutputStreamWriter directly and not use a buffer:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(mOutputToPort);
osw.write(mValue, 0, mValue.length());
osw.flush();
```

(In Java, Writers deal with writing characters to streams instead of bytes.)

If you want to ensure that no buffering occurs (and I doubt there is any reason for it, it will only increase system call overhead since the serial port will buffer the data anyway and send it out slower than your code delivers it), 123456789 provided a suitable answer. You should be careful with calling `getBytes()` though, as this will use the system's default character encoding (usually UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, both suitable for writing pure ASCII) to convert from characters to bytes. If you want a particular encoding then specify it in the call to `getBytes()`, e.g.

```
try {
    byte[] bytes = someString.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) 
        mOutputToPort.write(bytes[i]);    }
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {} // well, this one is always supported
```

Comment: Still serial port i.e.controller giving garbage value..dear i want to send some ascii char commands to a controller...

Comment: You see garbage? Are you sure your serial port is properly set up, i.e. word length, parity, symbol rate? It boils down to the question: does the code in your question yield readable output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getBytes() method which returns byte array.

```
   OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();

    String mValue = "ABCDEFG";
      System.out.println("beginning to Write . \r\n");
     Byte[] data = mValue.getBytes();
     for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     mOutputToPort.write(data[i]);}
     System.out.println("AT Command Written to Port. \r\n");
     mOutputToPort.flush();
```

Comment: You should always specify the encoding when using getBytes().

Comment: thanks frnd,but data[i] writes some ascii decimal values 65 66 67 some what like that..i want "ABCDEFG" as it is..